# Is it possible to send data from server to client without it being visible in network traffic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a drag and drop text game, where you have to match the correct pairs. When you are done, you click a button and then get a response on how many are right (and wrong). You continue until all are correct. The right/wrong score is logged, and then the boxes are restarted with new text and you go again. If you have a total of x wrong, you lose.

My problem is that the new text is sent from server and the array is found and visible in network traffic. Is there any way to hide this, or another way to update the boxes from server side, without finding the data in dev-tools?
I am using Node and Express, and I am new to web development. It might be an obvious answer to this, but I don't see it. And I have used so much time trying different solutions only to find out they don't work. And if I can't hide the data, what can I do so the answers can't easily be found in network traffic?

Comment: Why not just do the comparison of what the user entered to the correct answer on the server side so you don’t have to arbitrarily send all clients the correct answer…? This is a pretty typical design paradigm, don’t overthink it.

Comment: For me, checking the answers is not my main problem, it is populating the boxes by sending data from a database on the server to the public JS on client side, and without this new data being easy to find in dev-tools.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use-case for htmx

Answer (score 1):

Do not send the answers to the client until users are supposed to see them. Send only the questions with the first request, and send the answers with a second request when the user clicks the button.